# Django - DetailView and Templates

Tags: python, django

So, my issue is that I have a detailview, which displays a specific post from my database. I then, used get_context_data to then grab db values from a different model; however, it outputs something strange in my template.

What can I change in the template, in order for it to list every correct db value from that other model?

models.py

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_shortdesc = models.CharField(max_length=248)
    project_desc = models.TextField()

    def save(self):
        super(Projects, self).save()
        date = datetime.date.today()
        self.slug = '%i%i%i%s' % (
                date.year, date.month, date.day, slugify(self.project_title)
            )
        super(Projects, self).save()


class ProjectsToDo(models.Model):
    project_tododate = models.DateField()
    project_tododesc = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    project_id = models.ManyToManyField(Projects)
```

views.py

```
class ProjectDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Projects
    context_object_name = 'indprojects'
    template_name = 'projectpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['todolist'] = ProjectsToDo.objects.order_by('project_tododate')
        context['todoform'] = ProjectToDoForm()
        context['form'] = ProjectForm(instance=Projects.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Projects.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectDetail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

template

```
 {{todolist}}
```

This from the template, outputs:
`[<ProjectsToDo: ProjectsToDo object>, <ProjectsToDo: ProjectsToDo object>]` 
I've tried `{{todolist.project_tododesc}}`, and both outputted no data. I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a `unicode` method to your `ProjectsToDo` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you did not define a `__str__()` method if you are using Python 3 (or `__unicode__()` in Python 2.x) in class `ProjectsToDo`.

When you try to print a model instance, what happens is Django will look at `__str__()` to decide what to display.

[See here for more about `__str__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#str)

Comment: i just :fp: i should've known that

Comment: @user3186219 :) tricked me the first time when I did that too.

Comment: Another approach would be to have the template decide of how to render a todo, and explicitly loop over the list. For instance, `<ul>{% for item in todolist %}<li>{{item.something}}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>`